# Animated GIF in React Native with Expo

Tags: reactjs, native, gif

I cannot use fresco in android/app/build.gradle because I have expo RN build.
Even thought I have latest expo and RN and other libraries my GIF file is not showing up.
Can sb help me with this please?
Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/@kartikeyvaish/gif-example

Comment: I have it dynamic how do I solve this correctly, please?

  const activityGifs = {
    "Say (i love you) in a different language":
      "require(./assets/images/timer10s.gif)",
  };

Than view -> <Image source={{ currentActivityGif }} />
..?
Because this is not working for me neither :(

Comment: use switch statement for that

Comment: I got it - 
"Say (i love you) in a different language": require("./assets/images/timer10s.gif"),

Comment: Yes you can have a function called ```const renderGIF(gif) { switch (true) { case gif === 'ILoveYou': return require('./iloveyou.gif')}}```